# looking for a git workflow that supports nested develop branches

Tags: git, git-flow

Here's my problem - I have a codebase that has to be deployed to three different environments. 90% of the code is common. The other 10% is unique to each environment. I would like to use the git-flow workflow (master, develop), but I feel like I need a second layer of "develop" branches (develop_a, develop_b, develop_c) that are branched from "develop". If I were to do that I could make common code changes in "develop" and then periodically merge the develop changes into develop_a, develop_b, and develop_c. At the same time I can be working on issues specific to develop_a, develop_b, and develop_c in branches off of those branches.

Using this approach makes the "master" branch pretty much meaningless from the perspective of it being the place to go for releasable software. develop_a, develop_b, and develop_c are the branches that contain the full complement of software to be released for each environment. I'm trying to find out if there is some establish workflow or best practice that supports this. I don't think different repositories for a,b,c makes sense because of the large amount of common code.

I think the better/longer term solution would be to refactor the code in such a way as to create interfaces and classes that support the uniqueness of develop_a, develop_b and develop_c, with the version (a,b,c) to deployed being resolved at runtime (there are other concerns and complicating factors which could make that impossible). I believe I have the luxury of exploring that approach in the long-term, but I also have a short term need to get a workflow established so people can begin working on these versions so we can get them out in the field for testing in the near future.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at gitflow? https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

Comment: Sounds like you need git-worktree or just three repos with a single common submodule

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a perfect place to use a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

- Create a repository for the 90% common code.
- Create 3 more repositories for the individual code. In each of them you do `git submodule add [url to common repo]`.
- Now push each code fragment to the corresponding repository. This will take some refactoring.
- Do not touch the common code in the 'individual' repositories from now on.
- After changes to the common code base you push to the common repo. Then in the individual ones you update by `git submodule update`.
- When cloning a repo that contains a submodule you

  - clone the repo (contains the empty folder of the submodule),
  - `git submodule init`,
  - `git submodule update`.

You will then deploy the individual repositories. They now contain the common code as well as the individual rest in a runnable melange. And of cause you can use what ever branching scheme you want.

Comment: Thank you for the possible solution.  This, as well as the one that follows, both seem to capture the essence of what I think I want to achieve.  I plan to talk to the other developers and experiment with both to see if one fits better and feels better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to do anything at all, other than use the git-flow approach.

From reading your post, I have the impression that you have some core code, and some platform-specific code, and they are mixed together (since you mention refactoring to separate them).

I also have the impression that the platform-specific bits of code are orthogonal to each other- that is, code specific to platform A will have no effect on platform B, etc.

Thus, it seems to me that if you have developers making changes to core code, they need to test it across all the platforms to ensure they haven't made it platform-specific by mistake. So sharing the core code as rapidly as possible is a win.

If my understanding is correct, consider just maintaining a single repository but setting up three different targets {platform-A, platform-B, platform-C} in your build system. This should let your developers cooperate with each other on core changes, and will let you automatically test the code on all platforms when any commit occurs.

Later on, if you refactor the code to the point where you can separate out the A/B/C specific code, it might make sense to create submodules. But I still don't see why. Far easier IMO to just create subdirectories and maintain the tradition of everyone working closely together.

Comment: Thank you for the possible solution.  This, as well as the one that precedes, both seem to capture the essence of what I think I want to achieve.  I plan to talk to the other developers and experiment with both to see if one fits better and feels better than the other.